# Excel - Combine string from multiple columns with delimiters into one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have thousands of rows in the below format:

```
Image ID    Image Title       Image Caption

4867        Bedroom           Bedroom
4866|4865   Office|Kitchen    Office|Kitchen
```

I need to take related strings from these columns and combine them into a fourth column in this format:

```
Image ID    Image Title       Image Caption     Attachments

4867        Bedroom           Bedroom           {"image_attachments":[{"id":"4867","fields":{"title":"Bedroom","caption":"Bedroom"}}]}
4866|4865   Office|Kitchen    Office|Kitchen    {"image_attachments":[{"id":"4866","fields":{"title":"Office","caption":"Office"}}]},{"image_attachments":[{"id":"4865","fields":{"title":"Kitchen","caption":"Kitchen"}}]}
```

Can someone suggest the best way to accomplish this please? Many thanks.

Comment: use LEFT and RIGHT functions combined with INSTR function to split strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left/right/concatenate to accomplish this. It'll be a bit time consuming to match your syntax exactly, but here's a sample. Let me know if you get stuck. Notice that in order to include a double quote in a string in Excel, you use `"""`:

```
=CONCATENATE("""{image_attachments"":[{""",LEFT(A3,4))
```

Assuming that A3 is the cell containing the first Image ID, then the output is as follows:

> "{image_attachments":[{"4867

After you finish this for the case where only one Image ID is in the cell, I'd wrap the entire thing in `=IF(LEN(A3=4,DO THIS,IF(LEN(A3=9,DO THIS CODE),"")`